# Maven 3, Tomcat 8 deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment

currently I develop my applications with eclipse and I have configured tomcat's context.xml file in tomcat/config directory and all works fine.
But when I create war with mvn clean package command, I'd like to include into META-INF folder of the project, another customized context.xml file.
How can I do this?
I tried to create 2 profiles without success.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat's *context.xml* file is located under *$catalina_base/conf/* and can add things to that of your web application's context file. Add your (separate) web application's *context.xml* in Maven project at

```
src
 main
  webapp
   META-INF
    context.xml
```

Comment: I know it, but the problem in that I need to configure different context.xml per environment